# How to capture multiline repeated groups using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

I've been trying to write a regular expression in a Kotlin application that I can use to parse multiline journal entries that are delimited by means of a timestamp prefix like so:

```
28-03-2020 23:00:00 - This
is
line
1

28-03-2021 14:23:15 - This
is
line
2
```

Each repeating group should capture the timestamp (1) and all text that occurs until either the next timestamp pattern at the start of a line *or* the end of text (2).

So, in the example above I expect the following output:

### Match 1

**Group 1**: `28-03-2020 23:00:00`

**Group 2**: `This\nis\nline\n1\n`

### Match 2

**Group 1**: `28-03-2020 14:23:15`

**Group 2**: `This\nis\nline\n2\n`

So far, I've managed to conjure up a regular expression that can capture the first match using:

```
^(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) -([\s\S]*?)(?=^\d{2}.*?)
```

However, I've been unsuccessful in capturing as repeated groups so far.. can someone help?

I've setup this [regex101 session](https://regex101.com/r/SCOkMb/1) to test it.

Comment: Have you tried with findAll? https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/find-all.html

Comment: If you need some more help, please share yor Kotlin code: what do you mean by repeated groups? Also, your regex should look like `^(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) -([\s\S]*?)(?=^\d{2}|\z)` at least.

Comment: I've accepted The fourth bird's answer as it gave me what I need to complete my [Kotlin solution](https://ideone.com/QP3yvW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match:

> Each repeating group should capture the timestamp and all text
> that occurs until either the next timestamp pattern at the start of a
> line or the end of text.

you can capture the timestamp at the start of the string in group 1.

Without setting an end boundary like a newline or a digit at the start of the line, capture all lines that do not start with a timestamp like pattern using a negative lookahead in group 2.

```
^(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\h+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\h+-\h*(.*(?:\R(?!\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\h+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d).*)*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\h+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})` Capture **group 1**, match a datetime like pattern
- `\h+-\h*` Match `-` preceded by 1+ horizontal whitespace char and followed by optional ones
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `.*` Match the whole line
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\R` Match a newline
    - `(?!\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\h+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d)` Negative lookahead, assert not a datetime like pattern directly to the right
    - `.*` If the assertion in true, match the whole line
  - `)*` Match a newline and the rest of the line if it does not start with a datetime like pattern
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pi2JCV/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/daD4nl)

For example

```
String regex = "^(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\h+-\\h*(.*(?:\\R(?!\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d).*)*)";
String string = "28-03-2020 23:00:00 - This\n"
+ "is\n"
+ "line\n"
+ "1\n\n"
+ "28-03-2021 14:23:15 - This\n"
+ "is\n"
+ "line\n"
+ "2\n\n\n\n"
+ "28-03-2020 23:00:00 - This\n"
+ "is\n"
+ "12\n"
+ "line\n"
+ "1";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("--------------------");
}
```

Output

```
28-03-2020 23:00:00
This
is
line
1

--------------------
28-03-2021 14:23:15
This
is
line
2



--------------------
28-03-2020 23:00:00
This
is
12
line
1
--------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Pattern.DOTALL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "28-03-2020 23:00:00 - This\n"
        + "is\n"
        + "line\n"
        + "1\n"
        + "\n"
        + "28-03-2021 14:23:15 - This\n"
        + "is\n"
        + "line\n"
        + "2\n"
        + "\n";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(
        "(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\s*-\\s*(.*?)\n\n",
        Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Group 1 : " + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("Group 2 : " + m.group(2));
    }
}
```

output:

```
Group 1 : 28-03-2020 23:00:00
Group 2 : This
is
line
1
Group 1 : 28-03-2021 14:23:15
Group 2 : This
is
line
2
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "28-03-2020 23:00:00 - This\n"
            + "is\n"
            + "line\n"
            + "1\n"
            + "\n"
            + "28-03-2021 14:23:15 - This\n"
            + "is\n"
            + "line\n"
            + "2\n"
            + "\n";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("^(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}) -(?:[\\s\\D]*?)^(\\d{1,2})",Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher matcher = r.matcher(s);
    
    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Group 1 : " + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("Group 2 : " + matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

And the output is as below.

```
Group 1 : 28-03-2020 23:00:00
Group 2 : 1
Group 1 : 28-03-2021 14:23:15
Group 2 : 2
```